# What is the product of $p_i-1 \over p_i$

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, totient-function, infinite-product, primorial

I am trying to find the value of $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}{p_i-1 \over p_i}$ =  ${\lim_{x \to \infty}} {\phi(p_x!) \over p_x!}$ Where $p_x!$ is the $x$th primorial, and $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

I guess I can honestly say I have no idea where to start, other than just iteriating it manually (around $0.25$ maybe?)

Comment: If $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function, then for primes $p$, we have $\frac{\phi(p)}{p} = \frac{p-1}{p} \to 1$ as $p \to \infty$. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, I was pointing out that your statement "$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = 0$" wasn't correct.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, I read "lim inf ${\phi(n) \over n} = 0$" off wikipedia, but that must mean something else.

Comment: If you haven't encountered $\liminf$ before, it is possibly unwise to start digging into this area yet. Review some real analysis first. It's not a lot, but a little will help.

Comment: Already on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:-**

Note that, $$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p_i}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\zeta(1)}$$

Where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann-Zeta Function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRiemann_zeta_function&ei=J-6kVJWzFoSxuATczIKICQ&usg=AFQjCNGTjoNYtSUzPukK6rQSv9k0VC3_Kw).

Answer (score 1):

If $a_i$ is a positive sequence, and $\prod (1-a_i)$ converges to a non-zero value, then there is a general theorem which says that $\sum a_i$ must converge.

But $\sum_{p<x} \frac{1}{p} = O(\log \log x)$ is know to diverge.

In the above case, this means that the product converges to zero (which is often thought of as the equivalent of saying the product diverges.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the reciprocal $\displaystyle\prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{p_i}{p_i-1} = \prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}} = \prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p_i^j}$.

This can be written out as:

$\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2^1}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\cdots\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3^1}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\cdots\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{5^1}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\cdots\right) \cdots$

Each integer $n$ has a unique prime factorization $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$. So, when you multiply out that product, there is exactly one $\dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{p_1^{e_1}}\dfrac{1}{p_2^{e_2}} \cdots \dfrac{1}{p_r^{e_r}}$ term for each integer $n$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p_i^j} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}$ which diverges to $+\infty$. Hence, the reciprocal $\displaystyle\prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{p_i-1}{p_i}$ is $0$.

Note: This is a specific case of the more general [Euler Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerProduct.html): $\displaystyle \prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i^s}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^s}$.